# Html5 data-popup with .NET MVC 4 Razor EditorFor extension?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I want like to create a input box with a data-popup attribute like this:

`<input type="text" name="title"  data-popup="test">`

I tried to use

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name , new { data_popup = "Hashtag" })`

but the data-popup attribute is not rendered.
Is it possbile to add a attribute like data-popup for an editorfor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe if you use `TextBoxFor` instead in the same way, you will get the results you desire.

The reason being is EditorFor doesn't have a parameter for htmlAttributes, the parameter you are passing is the `additionalViewData` parameter, and therefore will not be rendered as html attributes..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but then you have to write your own editor markup (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html).  Otherwise, it is usually much easier to just use TextBoxFor instead.